# No entiendo porque me dice invalid syntax

Tags: python

Esoy usando python y no se porque me dice invalid syntax en el cierre de parentesis de 'ayuda'.

```
import webbrowser

print('MENU')

print(' Jugar ')
print(' Creditos')
elegir = input('elige:')
if elegir == 'Jugar' or 'jugar':
    print('Todo comienza..  cuando no hay nada que hacer')
if elegir == ('creditos') or ('Creditos'):
        print('Samisaw')
elif elegir == ('ayuda')
    webbrowser.open('google.com')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te he corregido varios errores que encontré, en los comentarios está todo explicado

```
import webbrowser

print('MENU')

print(' Jugar ')
print(' Creditos')
elegir = input('elige:')
# if elegir == 'Jugar' or 'jugar':  # No puedes añadir or "esto" a una comparación
# siempre debes poner la comparación de nuevo si lo haces así. Lo más corto sería hacer:
if elegir.lower() == "jugar":  # Pasando la variable a minúsculas solo hace falta comparar una vez
    print('Todo comienza..  cuando no hay nada que hacer')
elif elegir == 'creditos' or elegir == 'Creditos':  # No hacen falta paréntesis en las comparaciones de string
    print('Samisaw')  # Aquí tenías un nivel de indentación de más
elif elegir == 'ayuda':  # Aquí te faltaban los dos puntos
    webbrowser.open('google.com')
```

Comment: También puedes usar `if elegir in ['creditos', 'Credito']:`para escribir menos

Comment: Creo que lo normal es pasar todo a minúsculas/mayúsculas no? Así también te aseguras que el usuario no escriba `cReDiToS`... nunca hay que fiarse de los usuarios!